# Silverlight Images won't update

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight 4 project with a number of png images.  I load the images at runtime using

`StreamResourceInfo res = Application.GetResourceStream( new Uri( assemblyName + ";component/" + relativeUri, UriKind.Relative ) );`

and then

`var bmp = new BitmapImage( );
bmp.SetSource( res.Stream );`

The images themselves are in a folder; each image has Build Action = Resource, Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy.  They all load just fine.

Then, I replace one of the images.  The old one still loads.  I know I am pointing to the right place, because if I remove the images from the folder, the app doesn't show any.  But, when I put them back, I do not see the new ones; only the old ones.

Things I have tried:
1.  Clear the cache on my browser.
2.  Start up a browser that I never otherwise use.
3.  Take the images out of the project and put them back.
4.  Take the images out of the folder and put them back.
5.  Stop and restart the browser.
6.  Kill the development server.
7.  Delete all the files from obj and bin folders, both for the Silverlight app and the Web app, and rebuild.

I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Try to set [BitmapImage.CreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions(v=vs.95).aspx) to `IgnoreImageCache`.

Comment: One thing i did not understand, i'm sorry, did you try to change it in runtime or you change it and compile again? Thanks

Comment: I change and compile.  I've had some success with doing a complete Clean Solution and Rebuild.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the error here but i could not.